# jQuery .on() のセレクタの書き方について

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(a)
$(document).on("click", "div p", function () {
  alert('hoge1');
});

(b)
$("div").on("click", "p", function () {
  alert('hoge2');
});

(c)
$("div p").on("click", function () {
  alert('hoge3');
});
```

(a)：新しい div や p を追加してもすべて動作する
(b)：既存の div p と既存の div に p を追加した場合のみ動作する
(c)：既存の div p にのみ動作する（追加した要素では動作しない）
という理解で合っているでしょうか。

div が追加されないと分かっている場合は、(a)と(b)のどちらの書き方が望ましいでしょうか。
・処理速度
・メモリ使用量
などにおいて違いがありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a), (b), (c)の理解は問題ないです。

> div が追加されないと分かっている場合は、(a)と(b)のどちらの書き方が望ましいでしょうか。

これはイベント登録後に `p` を追加するが、 `div` 自体は追加しない、という理解でよろしいでしょうか。その場合は特に理由がない限り (b) を勧めます。 (a) はドキュメント上に存在するすべての要素に対してjQuery側の処理が発生してしまい、処理効率が悪いです。

(b) や (c) は `div` が極端に多い場合においてメモリを消費する問題がありますが、そうでなければ気にする必要はありません。例え多くても、 `div` の親要素を設けて、そこに `$("親要素を指定").on("click", "div p", function() {})` のようにイベントを貼れば解決できます。